# Delete logger lines from final jar while performing maven build or package

Tags: java, scala, maven, logging, maven-assembly-plugin

I know that it is possible to [delete or skip files and folders while doing maven clean](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/delete_additional_files.html).

My problem is that I want to delete some specific lines (`log.info` lines) from final jar while doing `mvn clean package`.

My full codebase is filled with logger lines similar to the following codebase:

```
class MyClass {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val log = Utils.getLogger
    log.info("Application started")

    val url = "https://sunilkumar.in"
    log.info(s"Trying to fetch content from url: $url")

    ...

    log.info("Successfully fetched content. Doing something now.")

    val v1 = "variable1"
    val v2 = "variable2"

    log.info(s"Starting to do something with v1: $v1 and v2: $v2")

    try {

      ...

      log.info("Successfully done something with variables")
    }
    catch {
      case e: Exception =>
        log.severe(s"Failed to do something. Got exception with message: ${e.getMessage}")
    }

    log.info("Continuing the work")

    ...

    log.info("Finished everything")
  }

}
```

- These logger information helps me a lot in understanding the problem
  and where my codebase failed with reason. So I cannot remove them
  because I need them during development.
- When I am building the Jar file for my clients (production artifact), I don't need any logging.
- If required I can use a pattern to identify logger lines by searching `log.info` as everywhere I am using the same variable name which is `log`.

**My question is:**

I don't know where and how to use this pattern to delete lines from final jar while doing `mvn clean build package` so that:

1. there should be no logging.
2. If I open up Jar file and convert `.class`
       to `.java` file then there should be no logging codebase.

**Note:**

- My project is a mixture of Java & Scala codebase and I want to delete
  all lines where `log.info` is found in any class be it Java or Scala in final jar.
- I am using `maven-assembly-plugin` to create `jar-with-dependencies` as final product.
- Any other solution is most welcomed.

Comment: Why do you need to do that (instead of configuring the logging system to not output anything at this log level)? A disabled logger is supposed to have extremely low overhead (precisely to avoid the need for this kind of conditional compilation).

Comment: You could also use `log.trace` or `log.debug` instead of `log.info` because those are not normally enabled by default, so you can selectively enable them for your development environment only (and not do anything special for the production deployment).

Answer (score 1):

Are you using slf4j, if so then consider setting the level to error. By setting it to error, none the log.info lines will get printed.

A sample config for reference

```
    <configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="60 seconds">

    <appender name="CONSOLE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ,UTC} %X{requestId} %X{req.remoteHost} %X{req.xForwardedFor}
                %X{req.requestURI} [%thread] %-5level [%logger{0}] %msg%n
            </pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Here, I am printing log.error to console, so info lines will not be printed.  By changing the level to info, you could print both info and error statements